# ViewModel unit test expected success but actual is null

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, mvvm, android-testing

I want to write a simple test for my `viewModel` to check if it gets data from `repository`. The app itself working without problem but in test, i have the following test failed.

It looks like the `viewModel` `init` block not running, because it suppose to call `getUpcomingMovies()` method in `init` blocks and post value to `upcomingMovies` live data object. When i test it gets `null` value.

Looks like i am missing a minor thing, need help to solve this.
Here is the test:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MoviesViewModelShould: BaseUnitTest() {

    private val repository: MoviesRepository = mock()
    private val upcomingMovies = mock<Response<UpcomingResponse>>()
    private val upcomingMoviesExpected = Result.success(upcomingMovies)

    @Test
    fun emitsUpcomingMoviesFromRepository() = runBlocking {
        val viewModel = mockSuccessfulCaseUpcomingMovies()

        assertEquals(upcomingMoviesExpected, viewModel.upcomingMovies.getValueForTest())
    }
    
    private fun mockSuccessfulCaseUpcomingMovies(): MoviesViewModel {
        runBlocking {
            whenever(repository.getUpcomingMovies(1)).thenReturn(
                flow {
                    emit(upcomingMoviesExpected)
                }
            )
        }
        return MoviesViewModel(repository)
    }
}
```

And viewModel:

```
class MoviesViewModel(
    private val repository: MoviesRepository
): ViewModel() {

    val upcomingMovies: MutableLiveData<UpcomingResponse> = MutableLiveData()
    var upcomingMoviesPage = 0
    private var upcomingMoviesResponse: UpcomingResponse? = null

    init {
        getUpcomingMovies()
    }

    fun getUpcomingMovies() = viewModelScope.launch {
        upcomingMoviesPage++
        repository.getUpcomingMovies(upcomingMoviesPage).collect { result ->
            if (result.isSuccess) {
                result.getOrNull()!!.body()?.let {
                    if (upcomingMoviesResponse == null) {
                        upcomingMoviesResponse = it
                    } else {
                        val oldMovies = upcomingMoviesResponse?.results
                        val newMovies = it.results
                        oldMovies?.addAll(newMovies)
                    }
                    upcomingMovies.postValue(upcomingMoviesResponse ?: it)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the result is:

```
expected:<Success(Mock for Response, hashCode: 1625939772)> but was:<null>
Expected :Success(Mock for Response, hashCode: 1625939772)
Actual   :null
```

Comment: If i can see it correctly, there is no point in where you collect your flow. You only return flow builder, which will do nothing by itself. Since flows are cold data streams, they won't emit anything until terminal operator is called.

Comment: Data is emitted in flow and assigned to the `upcomingMoviesExpected` which is working fine, it directly use repository method, i tested repository too. Then it returns instance of `MoviesViewModel`. In this viewModel i call `upcomingMovies` live data and compare them to see if my viewModel has the same data from repository or not. In the init block, it suppose to call `getUpcomingMovies` function and post value to `upcomingMovies`, but looks like it didn't so returns null. Looks like `return MoviesViewModel(repository)` is not activating it's init block so it gets data.